# Downgrade Windows 10 Education to Home without clean install

Tags: windows-10, product-key, downgrade

I have a Windows 10 laptop that was preinstalled with Windows 10 Home. Because I use this laptop for college, I have a product key for Windows 10 Education for some extra features (like remote desktop), and activated that key a few months ago.

Because I have almost finished college, the Education key should expire in a while.

Now I want to go back to the preinstalled Home edition, but can't find a way how. And I don't want to do a clean install.

I used the [ProduKey](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) tool to see my *BIOS OEM Key*, because there is no sticker on the laptop. Next, I tried to reactivate Windows with that key. No luck unfortunately. It returned an error (`0xc004f050`).

I also found [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTjLd57QgDY) to use a workaround with the register editor (regedit) and a re-install that keeps the files. But I am not sure if this is going to work with an educational license and an OEM key. This question was asked in the comments, but not answered.

So, is there a way to downgrade safely, without doing a clean install?

---

What if this is not possible? Will Windows automatically downgrade back to Home if the Education license expires? Does it uninstall the features that were installed during the upgrade to Education?

Comment: As far as I know downgrade back to your old W10 Home is not possible after 30 days....https://www.thewindowsclub.com/go-back-to-an-earlier-build-of-windows-10

Comment: And what if the license expires? Will it automatically downgrade? Of be stuck on Education in trial mode?

Comment: I don't know what  happens when it expires, no it will not automatically downgrade, it cannot. You will have to install Home manually.

Comment: Hmm. I guess I should try the YouTube video soon then... That's the only way to keep the files.

Comment: Are you even sure the key expires? Keys retrieved from Dreamspark Premium (MSDN AA) never expire and the license explicitly states you can keep using them for non-commercial uses.

Comment: @DanielB I've read somewhere that the key will expire as soon as I leave the school and my account is made inactive/deleted. But I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTjLd57QgDY) works for Windows Education as well.

You simply modify the Windows Registry and then create an ISO file using the [Media Creaton Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/nl-nl/software-download/windows10).

Next, reinstall Windows 10 with the option to keep your files. After a while, Windows 10 is installed.

Keep in mind to make a back up of your files. Just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: This did not work for me. I changed the registry from education to home and it changed back by itself. The new Windows 10 home license key was not accepted.